# How to get file size and current file size from NSURL for AVPlayer iOS4.0

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

```
self.player = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/track.mp3"]] retain];
```

I am trying make a UIProgressView for the above track. How do I obtain the file size and current file size from that URL? Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to start observing the loadedTimeRanges property of the current item, like this:

```
AVPlayerItem* playerItem = self.player.currentItem;
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:kLoadedTimeRanges options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:playerItemTimeRangesObservationContext];
```

Then, in the observation callback, you make sense of the data you're passed like this:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)aPath ofObject:(id)anObject change:(NSDictionary*)aChange context:(void*)aContext {

if (aContext == playerItemTimeRangesObservationContext) {

    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = (AVPlayerItem*)anObject;
    NSArray* times = playerItem.loadedTimeRanges;

    // there is only ever one NSValue in the array
    NSValue* value = [times objectAtIndex:0];

    CMTimeRange range;
    [value getValue:&range];
    float start = CMTimeGetSeconds(range.start);
    float duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(range.duration);

    _videoAvailable = start + duration; // this is a float property of my VC
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateVideoAvailable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Then the selector on the main thread updates a progress bar, like so:

```
-(void)updateVideoAvailable {

    CMTime playerDuration = [self playerItemDuration];
double duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(playerDuration);
    _videoAvailableBar.progress = _videoAvailable/duration;// this is a UIProgressView
}
```

Comment: What is kLoadedTimeRanges supposed to represent? I can't find this anywhere

Comment: just to prevent copy & paste error. make sure you test the times array for count > 0. in iOS 8 it can return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not want to know anything about file-sizes, but you're more interested in times.

Try `self.player.currentItem.asset.duration` for duration of currently playing item, `self.player.currentTime` for current time.

Comment: Yep, Im making the slider with the duration. But if the user slides pass what is loaded, then bad news. So I want progress of the downloaded/playing track, is that right? Does that make sense?

Comment: I understand, I'm not sure about this, but you might want to enable seeking only within ranges specified in `self.player.currentItem.loadedTimeRanges`.

Comment: Yea I will need to do that too. But still would be nice for the users to see what has loaded. Like a real streamer.

Comment: Hey Michal, can you explain a little bit how to use loadedTimeRange? I don't know how to get the duration from CMTimeRange.

Answer (score 0):

@"loadedTimeRange" is a KVO value for the AVPlayerItem class. You can find its definition in the AVPlayerItem.h file in the

```
@interface AVPlayerItem (AVPlayerItemPlayability)
```

category definition.