# How to show buffer progress on AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, iphone, progress-bar, audio-streaming, avplayer

I have a music player application that allow user to stream song from server. I've been able to stream song from url using AVPlayer. I want to achieve something like below:

[image]

I've tried to convert top answer from this [How to get file size and current file size from NSURL for AVPlayer iOS4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999228/how-to-get-file-size-and-current-file-size-from-nsurl-for-avplayer-ios4-0) post to swift, but I can't find the "kLoadedTimeRanges".

And here is my code:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if object as? NSObject == songPlayer && keyPath == "status" {

        if songPlayer?.status == AVPlayerStatus.Failed {

            println("AVPlayerStatusReadyToFailed")

        }else if songPlayer?.status == AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay {

            println("AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay")
            self.songPlayer!.play()

        }else if songPlayer?.status == AVPlayerStatus.Unknown {

            println("AVPlayerStatusReadyToUnknown")

        }

    }
}

@IBAction func playAction(sender: UIButton) {

    var songUrl = "http://a575.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/119/Music/v4/67/9d/b0/679db0ba-a7f4-35ea-3bf1-e817e7bcf11f/mzaf_3227008615944938675.aac.m4a"
    var songPlayerItem = self.songPlayer?.currentItem
    self.songPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: songUrl))
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: self.songPlayer?.currentItem)

    self.songPlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: nil, context: nil)
    //NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "updateProgress:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

I'll appreciate any suggestion, doesn't matter using objective c or swift

Answer (score 2):

**Objective C:**
Note: I made a custom UISlider ([Buffer Slider](https://github.com/abhimuralidharan/BufferSlider/blob/master/README.md)) where I added one UIProgressView to show the buffer progress.`setBufferValue` method shown in the code below is a custom method which will set the `UIProgressView` value.

```
static void *PlayerViewControllerLoadedTimeRangesObservationContext = &PlayerViewControllerLoadedTimeRangesObservationContext;

[self.playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:PlayerViewControllerLoadedTimeRangesObservationContext];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*) path
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary*)change
                       context:(void*)context
{
    if (context == PlayerViewControllerLoadedTimeRangesObservationContext) {
        NSArray *timeRanges = (NSArray*)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

        if (timeRanges && [timeRanges count]) {
            CMTimeRange timerange=[[timeRanges objectAtIndex:0]CMTimeRangeValue];
            float bufferTimeValue=CMTimeGetSeconds(timerange.duration)/CMTimeGetSeconds(_player.currentItem.duration);
            [self.playerSlider setBufferValue:bufferTimeValue>.95?1:bufferTimeValue animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this code has not been accepted? Very simple and usefull.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
[avPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

kLoadedTimeRanges is probably just defined as

```
static NSString *kLoadedTimeRanges = @"loadedTimeRanges";
```